# Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{' , while inside html if loop

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

I am creating a table in html, but if the value that will be outputted is equal to the value above I want to merge the cells. I am sure that all the variables work as they are correct later. However, when I use them in the if loop I get an error

```html
<table>

    <tr>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>peptide_id</th>
        <th>protein_id</th>
        <th>group_id</th>
        <th>search_id</th>
        <th>peptide_parsimony</th>
    </tr>


{% for elem in elem_list %}

    <tr>

    {% for sub_elem in elem %}
        elem.2 =
        {% if  {{ elem.2 }} == {{sub_elem}} %}
        <td>  </td>

        {% else %}


        <td onclick="location.href='/protein/proteinseq/{{ elem.1}}/{{ elem.2 }}/{{ elem.4 }}/'" style = " text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer" >{{ sub_elem }}</td>

        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

This gives me the error :

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{' from '{{'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use tag or variable brackets when you are already within a tag.

```
{% if elem.2 == sub_elem %}
```

Comment: Thanks this works great but do you have any idea how to merge cells if they have the same value as the one before it? This would only have to be for one specific row. Should I save the previous rows output as a variable in JS and then use that to compare to the current element? However, I do not have much experience with this and would not really know how to do it.

Comment: No you shouldn't use JS for things like that. The [`ifchanged` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged) could probably help you.

Comment: How would I merge the cells after finding out if they are the same? Also I would still need to save the previous column's cell in a variable to use the ifchanged filter right?

Comment: Because elem.2 does not change within the second for loop I would have to assign a variable to check to the previous loop right? How else would I be able to do it?

Comment: Is there no way to do this?